# passing to model through controller in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter, select

I want to select an option of product categories from dropdown menu and show products that have that specific category.

Here is the form part from **my view**:

```
<?php $attributes = array('method'=>"POST", "class" => "myc",  "id" => "myc", "name" => "dropdwn");
            echo form_open_multipart('frontend/home/display', $attributes); ?> 
          <div class="form-group">

                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <select class="form-control"  name="category" onchange="this.form.submit();" />


                                <option value="" <?php echo set_select('category', 'zero', TRUE); ?>>Categories...</option>

                                <option value="phone" >Phones</option>
                                <option value="laptops">Laptops</option>
                                <option value="accessories" >Accessories</option>

                            </select>

                        </div>
                    </div>

  <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

As you can see I get the option from dropdown through onchange="this.form.submit(); 
(if it's not a good idea please suggest other way to do, I just didn't want to use ajax, as I'm not so good at it yet, anyhow suggest what seems better).

Then in my controller I get the option and convert it to array, to use it in my model.

**controller part:**

```
public function display($sort_by='product_id', $sort_order='asc', $offset = 0) 
    {
 $this->load->model('model_product');
$selected = implode(" ", $this->input->post());
        //var_dump($selected);
 $results = $this->model_product->fetch($selected, $limit, $offset, $sort_by, $sort_order);
        $data['products'] = $results['rows'];
        $data['num_results'] = $results['num_rows'];
//and then goes pagination part, I guess no meaning posting it, as it works fine.
}
```

**My model:**

```
function fetch($selected, $limit, $offset, $sort_by, $sort_order)
     {
        $sort_order = ($sort_order == 'desc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
        $sort_columns = array('product_id', 'name', 'description', 'category', 'country', 'price');
        $sort_by = (in_array($sort_by, $sort_columns)) ? $sort_by : 'product_id';


        //actual results query
        $q = $this->db->select('product_id, name, description, category, country, price, img_name, thumb_name')
            ->from('products')
            ->where('category', $selected)
            ->limit($limit, $offset)
            ->order_by($sort_by, $sort_order);


        $ret['rows'] = $q->get()->result();
        var_dump($ret['rows']);
        die;
        //count query
        $q = $this->db->select('COUNT(*) as count', FALSE)
           ->from('products');

        $tmp = $q->get()->result();
        $ret['num_rows'] = $tmp[0]->count;
        return $ret;
     }
```

Here I get no results, probobly because where clause returns no result.
However if I change the where clause such as ->where('category', 'phones') it shows only phones. *So how can I pass selected value to the query correctly?*

Answer (score 0):

i wil help you. 
View file

```
 <div class="box-header">
                                <h3 class="box-title">Enter Category Details</h3>
                            </div>

                            <?php
                           echo validation_errors();                                   $attributes = array('id' => 'formCategory','name'=>'formCategory'); 
                            ?>
                            <?php echo form_open_multipart(base_url().'moderator/B2BCategory/addcategory'); ?>

                            <div class="box-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="txtcatname">Title of Category :</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="txtcatname" class="form-control" id="txtcatname" placeholder="Category Name " required="required">
                                        </div>
                                    </div> 
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="categorysection">Section of the Category :</label>
                                            <select class="form-control" name="categorysection"  required>
                                            <option value="" >----Select------</option>
                                            <option value="1">Laptop</option>
                                            <option value="2">Phone</option>
                                          <option value="3">Accessories</option>

                                             </select>
  <input type="submit" name="selsub" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        </div>
                                    </div> 


      </div>
```

Controller

```
  public function addcategory() {
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
            $this->load->view('moderator/templates/header');
            $this->load->view('moderator/templates/sidebar');
     if ($this->input->post('selsub')) {
 $data = array('ctg_name' => $this->input->post('categorysection'));
  $this->b2bcategory_model->form_insert($data);
    }
```

In Model

```
public function form_insert($data){

$this->db->insert('jil_category', $data);
}
```

To display output from table,just use

```
 public function viewall()
   {

        $this->db -> select('*');
        $this -> db -> from('jil_category');
        $query = $this -> db -> get();
         return $query->result();

   }
```

Comment: if you want to list the added product list from database,just use the following code

Answer (score 0):

From

```
$selected = implode(" ", $this->input->post());
```

To

```
$selected = $this->input->post('category');
```

By the way, `echo` & `var_dump()` would be very useful in debugging your controller and/or model.

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys, actually everything is working okay, my bad, I had a typo in the name of my select form, which didnt correspond to the data in the db